# Prove that the equation $x^4+y^4+z^4-2x^2y^2-2y^2z^2-2z^2x^2=24$ has no solutions in integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that the equation $x^4+y^4+z^4-2x^2y^2-2y^2z^2-2z^2x^2=24$ has no solutions in integers.

My work:
When $x,y,z$ are all even no solution exists as the LHS is divisible by 16 whereas RHS is not.
So now, remains two cases:
*i)* One of $x,y,z$ is odd and two are even.
*ii)* Two of $x,y,z$ are odd and one is even.

Case *i)* -say $x$ is odd. LHS stands as $x^4+16k_1+16k_2-8k_3x^2-32k_4-8k_4x^2$. We are now to consider, $x^4-2x^2y^2-2x^2z^2$ as other elements are divisible by $16$. If we can prove that this part is divisible by $16$ then we are done but I cannot do that.

As for Case *ii)* I could not think of how to show it divisible by $16$. So, I think I need to find out something else that works which I could not. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting the equation as $(x^2-y^2-z^2)^2=4(6+x^2y^2)$?

Comment: Just throw it in and expand?

Comment: @AndreaMori I cannot see now, how that will help.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Thank you for the identification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equation can be rewritten as
$$
(x^2-y^2-z^2)^2=4(6+y^2z^2)
$$
The LHS is a square, $4$ is a square, so also $6+x^2y^2$ needs to be a square. But also $y^2z^2$ is a square.

Are there two squares in $\Bbb Z$ whose difference is $6$?

Comment: This is true...and really elegant solution. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @CalvinLin : yes, of course! I made the correction, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just throw it in and expand.

Case i) If only 1 of them is odd, show that the expression is odd, hence not 24.

Case ii) Set $ x = 2a+1, y = 2b+1, z = 2c $.

See [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282a%2B1%29%5E4+%2B+%282b%2B1%29%5E4+%2B+%282c%29%5E4+-+2%282a%2B1%29%5E2+%282b%2B1%29%5E2+-+2%282b%2B1%29%5E2+%282c%29%5E2+-+2%282c%29%5E2+%282a%2B1%29%5E2). It is a multiple of 16, and so we're done.

Comment: I also need to prove the case i which I could not complete.

Comment: @Hawk That case is pretty obvious, if you know what you're supposed to show.

Comment: Indeed...thanks for the help, though I should have been able to do this.

Comment: for last case: LHS=$((x+y)(x-y))^2+z^4-2z^2(x^2+y^2),x+y=2p,x-y=2q,x^2+y^2=2r \implies $ LHS=$16t$